# ASP.NET Core Virual Application doesnt load typescript files When Host in IIS

Tags: typescript, iis-7, asp.net-core-2.0, virtualhost

I am trying to host ASP.NET Core 2.0 application as virtual in iis. It doesnt load type scripts files and it shows below error.
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading https://mywebsite/planner/traceur

How to load the ts files in virtual application?

Comment: So you're getting a 404. There could be any number of reasons for that, but without code, it's absolutely impossible to say. The URL you posted isn't a path to a specific file, so there's likely some issue in your routing.

Comment: @ChrisPratt The ts file is loading properly when running on local. But it is not loading after hosted in iis. I have hosted my application as virtual directory